# How would I say "Or, call us at (phone number)" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would I say "Or, call us at (phone number)" in German, or perhaps "Or, contact us at (phone number)? This is to be placed next to an e-mail contact form. The tone of the site is professional (industrial business) yet welcoming to visitors.

Comment: Oder telefonisch unter ###-###-####.

Answer (score 11):

I'd say

> 1) ... oder rufen Sie uns unter dieser Nr. an: (phone number)

or

> 2) ... oder rufen Sie uns an unter (phone number)

or

> 3) ... oder erreichen Sie uns telefonisch unter (phone number)

I googled quickly and found some official websites (public authorities) saying

> 4) Telefonisch erreichen Sie uns unter (phone number)

Personally, I tend to use option 2), it is professional and friendly.

Comment: This covers pretty much all used varieties, and I would prefer #3 or #4.

Comment: where `Nr.` = Nummer

Comment: Oder `oder rufen Sie uns unter Plaza-404 an` oder `oder kontaktieren Sie uns unter 110 112 123456`

Comment: "Oder rufen Sie uns an: XXXXX XXXXXXXXX"

Answer (score 3):

I’d write: „Sie können uns auch unter (Telefonnummer) anrufen.“

Starting a sentence with „Oder“ is often considered less good style. Sentry’s option 4 also avoids this, but is more formal.

Answer (score 2):

I like to say

> Bitte schreiben Sie uns ein Email oder rufen Sie uns einfach an unter 0176...

I add "*einfach*" for the effect of "*or **simply** call us at*". I like to use the word *simply* because it gives the impression that you are more welcome if you call us.

Comment: Ich gebrauche „Email“ als weiblich. Ich weiß nicht, ob verschiedene Geschlechter gebräuchlich ist, aber zumindest würde ich von der Neutrumsform abraten, da der Leser darüber stolpern könnte.